# splice uploaded video into 1mb chunks in php

Tags: php, video

Assuming a user has just uploaded a **10mb MP4** video called `video.mp4` through a form input with the name `video`.

Would it be possible to "splice" up the video into 10 1mb chunks, or are there any libraries available which would be able to do this?

This way, when a video is selected to load inside the `<video>` tag, it will use the first one of those chunks of videos to play first, then load the rest while the other is playing and essentially stack them on the ends of each clip.

I know it seems like a pretty broad question, but I can't seem to find any other post similar to this (or any other solutions for that matter).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://github.com/PHP-FFMpeg/PHP-FFMpeg which is pretty mature and well documented.

In your case, what you're interested in is the clip method:

```
$video->filters()->clip(FFMpeg\Coordinate\TimeCode::fromSeconds(30), FFMpeg\Coordinate\TimeCode::fromSeconds(15));
```

Comment: Yeah, I was having a look at that beforehand. However, it seemed like a bit of an unnecessary hassle. any idea on how to install on a Windows system? Or, any other raw alternative? Thanks :)

Comment: How is it a hassle? It does what it's supposed to do, it streamlines working with videos in php, without having to work directly with ffmpeg (or other tools) with sys_pipe commands.

Comment: not the general use of it, just the installation. :/ I've never actually installed a 3rd party library before, so it is a bit confusing

Comment: A good time to learn, I'd say, it's not that difficult and there is documentation to help you.

Comment: definitely! :) would you be able to link me to one?

Comment: Install ffmpeg https://www.assetbank.co.uk/support/documentation/install/ffmpeg-debian-squeeze/ffmpeg-debian-jessie/ and for PHP-FFMpeg use composer https://getcomposer.org/doc/faqs/how-do-i-install-a-package-to-a-custom-path-for-my-framework.md (or https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E8omrqGJWSw)

Comment: Thankyou! :) will try this now

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't really need to do this so long as your server supports range requests:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_serving

This will allow the client, i.e. the browser, to request chunks of the file at a time form the server and start playing back as soon as it had enough to star the video.

If you are concerned about user experience then you probably want to go a bit further and support multiple bit rates and a streaming protocol which support bit rates changes such as HLS or MPEG-DASH. This will allow for different quality video chunks to be survived depending on network conditions.

At this point you are generally better to use a dedicated Video server or video hosting service as the functionality is relatively complex and specialised and its generally easier than re-creating it yourself. Open source streaming server exist such as:

- https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org
- http://www.videolan.org/vlc/streaming.html